# How do I write SQL query for the website traffic

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `record` with the columns:

```
userId

ip

timestamp

userAgent
```

How do I write a query that will list the site traffic per month (measured in # of logins) from January 2017 through December 2017

Comment: Please tag the question with the database that you are using.

Comment: @Popeye I use MySQL database for the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` as follows:

```
select userId, date_trunc('month', timestamp) as Month_, count(*)
From your_table t
Where year(timestamp) = 2017
group by userId, date_trunc('month', timestamp) ;
```